# <script> is loaded but not visible in chrome sources

Tags: javascript, html

In the below piece of code if I comment the empty script tag then main.js is not visible in chrome dev tools sources tab but in the network tab i can see the request for main.js is successful.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Typescript Project</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function load() {
            console.log(user);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="main.js"/>
<!--comment the below script tag to break code-->
<script></script>

</body>
</html>


// main.js
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}
var user = "Jane User";
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

Can someone please explain this behavior. Thanks

Comment: As a note `<script src="main.js"/>` is equal to `<script src="main.js">` the `/` at the end does not have any effect. In `html` elements are either  _self closing_ or not. The `/` at the end is xml/xhtml.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the script tag `<script src="main.js"></script>` like this

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="main.js"/>
```

is NOT valid html tag.

It looks like you were digging to deep with it.

Different browsers handle invalid HTML tag differently.

So what should I say, follow the specification.

Comment: Ya .. it didn't strike me. :)

Answer (score 0):

write like this

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
<head>
<title>Typescript Project</title>

 </head>
  <body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

because

```
 <script src="main.js"/> is not a valid way to call your reference  script file that,s why it is not working the tag is wrong
```

Comment: Thanks .. i was not aware of it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Typescript Project</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function load() {
            console.log(user);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="main.js" ></script> <!--changed-->
<!--comment the below script tag to break code-->
<script></script>

</body>
</html>

<script> <!--changed-->
// main.js
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}
var user = "Jane User";
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
</script><!--changed-->
```